# How to specify a condition on a @ManyToMany while still eager loading all entities?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a `Restaurant` entity, that can have many `Cuisines` (Italian, Sushi, etc.):

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Restaurant
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cuisine")
     */
    protected $cuisines;
}
```

When I load a list of restaurants, I want to eager load its cuisines, to avoid a round-trip to the database when calling `getCuisines()` on each restaurant. Using DQL:

```sql
SELECT r, c
FROM Model\Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN r.cuisines c
```

All good.

Now if I want to return all restaurants that contain a given cuisine, I can use this DQL:

```sql
SELECT r
FROM Model\Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN r.cuisines c
WHERE c.id IN (?)
```

That's fine as well. Now if I want to do both at the same time:

```sql
SELECT r, c
FROM Model\Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN r.cuisines c
WHERE c.id IN (?)
```

The list of restaurants will be correct, but their `$cuisines` will only be populated with the ones whose ID match the given list. This totally breaks the model.

**How can I restrict the returned restaurants by cuisine, while still eager loading the full list of cuisines?**

Comment: When you received the restaurants, couldn't you just get the cuisines by getting the ArrayCollection with r->getCousines()?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having it **always** eager load cuisines:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cuisine", fetch="EAGER")
 */
```

Otherwise... it's hard.  If it were `OneToMany` you could temporarily change it for just that query: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql

But with a `ManyToMany` you can't do it on a per-query basis.

Comment: Sorry, it *is* a `OneToMany` at the moment (maybe it shouldn't). I updated the question code to match the title. I didn't know that eager fetching actually executed a second query (this is good!): I thought that it transparently joined the second table. I can't find anywhere in the doc you pointed to, that this is specific to `OneToMany`, though? What prevents it from being used on a `ManyToMany`?

Comment: Argh, I'm getting confused. It **is** a `ManyToMany` with a join table at the moment. I updated the question again. still, is it anywhere mentioned that the temporary fetch mode doesn't work on `ManyToMany`?

Comment: It says on that page: "Changing the fetch mode during a query is only possible for one-to-one and many-to-one relations."

Comment: I needed sleep. Indeed, it's written pretty clearly. I'm not against setting it permanently in the annotation, but I just tested this, and it doesn't seem to be taken into account when using DQL. It still performs N+1 queries; is this fetch mode maybe only effective when using `find*()` methods in the entity manager / repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am getting this wrong, but normally you should be able to get the whole ArrayCollection without specifying it in the query.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('r')
   ->from('Model\Restaurant', 'r')
   ->leftJoin('r.cuisines', 'c')
   ->where('c.id IN ?1')
   ->setParameter(1, $ids);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();

foreach ($result as $restaurant){
    //contains the whole arrayCollection
    var_dump($restaurant->getCuisines());
}
```

In your Restaurant Entity make sure to have a constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->cuisines = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: As I'm mentioning in the question, it works, but it performs N+1 queries, where N is the number of restaurants. The whole point is to do it in 1 query with eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

In your current query you limit the result set by the properties of the `Cuisines` model - thus you will not get all relations of the restaurant you are trying to fetch. Try using a subselect as follows:

```sql
SELECT r, c
FROM Model\Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN r.cuisines c
WHERE r.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT sr.id 
    FROM Model\Restaurant sr
    LEFT JOIN sr.cuisines sc 
    WHERE sc.id IN (?)
)
```

**Explanation:** The sub select executes the same query that you developed above to fetch both at the same time. However, we are only returning the restaurant ids that fulfill the criteria. Then, in the main select we fetch all those restaurants with *all* their cuisines.

Comment: It's a ManyToMany relationship, so Cuisines don't have a `restaurantId`!

Comment: You are absolutely right! I am sorry to not have seen the hint. I updated the query to reflect the `manyToMany` relationship. Now it should work how you expect it to work.